# Is there a formal definition of machine?

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, soft-question

In physics, especially in mechanics, textbooks talk of machines. But I have never actually come upon a formal definition of machines. Is there in some text a formal, rigorous definition of when a physical system is a machine?

Comment: What would you need such a definition *for*? I don't understand why you claim that mechanics textbooks "talk of machines". In my experience they talk about balls on springs or blocks on ramps, etc., not "machines".

Comment: Does the following not satisfy you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine If a textbook were to use machine to mean something more specific, I think this would be mentioned in the text...

Answer (score 1):

I'd think at a machine from different points of view:

- from the point of view of balance of physical quantities, I'd think in terms of:

  - **system**: all the components, or the union of subsets of components grouped in subsystems, you're directly interested in;
  - **external environment**: anything is not the system;
- from an system theory/control point of view, I'd think as a system with:

  - internal state
  - controllable input
  - exhogenous input
  - output

### Balance of physical quantities

I'd do so, because many principles of physics are written as balance of variables of a system, as the result with the interaction with the external environment, and possibly some internal dynamics. As an example,

- Newton's second principle of dynamics states that the time derivative of the momentum of a system equals the external forces acting on it

  $\dfrac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt}  = \mathbf{F}^{ext}$
- dynamical equation for the angular momentum $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_H$ w.r.t. a pole $H$, relates the time derivative of the angular momentum of the system with the motion of the pole and the external moments acting on the system:

  $\dfrac{d\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_H}{dt} = -\dot{\mathbf{x}}_H \times \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{M}_H^{ext}$
- first principle of thermodynamics states that the time derivative of the total energy equals the sum of the power of the external forces acting on the system and the heat transfer with the external environment,

  $\dfrac{d E^{tot}}{dt} = P^{ext} + \dot{Q}^{ext}$.

### Dynamical system

Usually you can write the governing equations of a general system as

$\underline{f}(\underline{\dot{x}}, \underline{x}, \underline{u}, \underline{d}, t) = 0$
$\underline{y} = \underline{g}(\underline{x}, \underline{u}, \underline{d}, t)$

where the first set of equations represents the governing equations of the system in implicit form, that usually takes the form of differential equations or differential algebraic equations if some algebraic constraint is present, being $\underline{x}$ the set of state of the system, $\underline{u}$ the input variable you can set to control the system (that depends on the actuators you have installed in your system), $\underline{d}$ the exhogenous input, like disturbances; the second set of equations relates the measurements you have $\underline{y}$ (that are closely related with the sensors you have installed in your system) with the state and the inputs  of the system.